# Show View on the top of navigation bar

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a custom navigation and Home view in my app. On the click of button I want to show a View just like a left side view ( width is not equal to screen width) , on the top of navigation. 
I have tried this:

LeftView.Layer.ZPosition = 1;

It is not working. If I set the Z index of navigation to -1, this hides complete navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what is happening..

Comment: I have added the screenshot for the above

Comment: TheAppMentor's answer below is the best approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:yourSubView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add that view to UIWindow. This will add your view above navigation bar.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:yourView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom navigation bar to the main view manually instead of using navigation controller's standard navigation bar. Then add your `leftview` as `subview`, in your `main view`. It will overlap navigation bar in this hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct answer:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:yourSubView];
```

Though it will not set the correct frame for the view, To set the correct frame for your view on the navigation bar, you have to set it in the viewDidAppear.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];  
   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:mTitleView];
}
```